# Parsing floating number from ping output in text file

Tags: python, regex, ping, text-parsing

So I am writing this python program that must extract the round trip time from a text file that contains numerous pings, whats in the text file I previewed below:

```
 64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=12.6ms
 64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=1864ms
 64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=107.8ms
```

What I want to extract from the text file is the 12.6, 1864, and the 107.8. I used regex to do this and have the following:

```
  import re
  ping = open("pingoutput.txt")
  rawping = ping.read()
  roundtriptimes = re.findall(r'times=(\d+.\d+)', rawping)
  roundtriptimes.sort()
  print (roundtriptimes)
```

The issue I'm having is that I believe the numbers are being read into the roundtriptimes list as strings so when I go to sort them they do not sort as I would like them to.

Any idea how to modify my regex findall command to make sure it recognizes them as numbers would help tremendously! Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314093/parsing-text-file-in-python/314095#314095http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314093/parsing-text-file-in-python/314095#314095 I already answer you, even with **full working**  python code...

Comment: @GillesQuenot I just saw this after posting an answer. That is very unfortunate. There is in fact a fully functional Python solution in your answer (and actually a regex that is better than mine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do that in RegEx, but if you add the following line before the sort, it should take care of it for you:

```
roundtriptimes[:] = [float(x) for x in roundtriptimes]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Non-regex:

Simply performing splits on space, grabbing the last entry, then split on `=`, grab the second part of the list and omit the last two components (ms). Cast to a float.

All of that is done in a list-comprehension:

Note that `readlines` is used to have a list containing each line of the file, which will be much easier to manage.

```
with open('ping_results.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

times = [float(line.split()[-1].split('=')[1][:-2]) for line in data]
print(times) # [12.6, 1864.0, 107.8]
```

## regex:

The key thing here is to pay attention to the regex being used:

```
time=(\d*\.?\d+)
```

Look for `time=`, then start a capture group `()`, and grab digits (`\d*`), optional decimal (`\.?`), digits (`\d+`).

```
import re

with open('ping_results.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

times = [float(re.findall('time=(\d*\.?\d+)', line)[0]) for line in data]
print(times) # [12.6, 1864.0, 107.8]
```

Comment: that's giving me an IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @SZapata I made a slight update to my regex (However it still worked with the older regex). However, by using your sample data in a file and copy pasting my code. Everything is working fine for me.